# Jumping Navbar - Materializecss

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm creating a website using Materializecss. All works nice and smooth, but I got one problem that I can't get my head around. I'm using jQuery to change from the normal navbar to the search field navbar when clicking the search icon. It works, but the content on the pages makes a little jump upwards when the change happens. I can't find the reason to this. Does anyone have any idea?

See link for example:

http://webbkurs.ei.hv.se/~hani0008/mlslp/main-mz.html

Also, does anyone know how I can skip the first step of the search bar, and go directly to the actual search field. As it is now the user has to click one extra time.

/Håkan

Comment: Your header should be 64px high. However, when you have the ul which contains your icons visible, it pushes the header's height to 73px. Setting a max-height 64px on the containing ul should sort this out. Alternatively, add overflow: hidden; to #navbar.

Comment: Cheer! That overflow: hidden; did the trick!

Comment: And as far as your second question is concerned, all you need to do is to add `$("input[type=search]").focus();` to your JS for skipping the first step of the user having to click on the search bar to go to the search field.

Comment: Great! Thank, that worked perfect!